# proof of being tangentical

Tags: geometry

Let $r_1$, $r_2$, $r_3$, and $r_4$ denote the radii of the incircles in the four triangles APB, BPC, CPD, and DPA respectively. Chao and Simeonov proved that the quadrilateral is tangential if and only if:

$\frac{1}{r_1}+\frac{1}{r_3}=\frac{1}{r_2}+\frac{1}{r_4}$

[image]

I can't find a proof for this can you prove it I also cannot do anything special.

Comment: The paper here: http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2009volume9/FG200910.pdf says that Wu proved this.  You can maybe follow the reference from there?

Comment: thanks if you want reputation write the answer I will accept it ang give it positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the article referred to above is not readily available to those without access to good online libraries and it contains a couple of typos and other obscurities, the following may be useful.

Take $PA,PB,PC,PD$ to be $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ respectively and $AB,BC,CD,DA$ to be $a,b,c,d$ respectively. We have area $APB=\frac{1}{2}(a+p_1+p_2)r_1$ and also $\frac{1}{2}p_1p_2\sin\angle APB$. So $\frac{\sin\angle APB}{r_1}=\frac{a}{p_1p_2}+\frac{1}{p_1}+\frac{1}{p_2}$. We get similar relations from triangles $BPC,CPD,DPA$ and hence $$\left(\frac{1}{r_1}+\frac{1}{r_3}-\frac{1}{r_2}-\frac{1}{r_4}\right)\sin\angle APB=\frac{a}{p_1p_2}+\frac{c}{p_3p_4}-\frac{b}{p_2p_3}-\frac{d}{p_1p_4}$$ Multiplying and dividing the rhs by $\left(\frac{a}{p_1p_2}+\frac{c}{p_3p_4}\right)+\left(\frac{b}{p_2p_3}+\frac{d}{p_1p_4}\right)$ we get $$\frac{p_1p_2p_3p_4\left(\frac{a}{p_1p_2}+\frac{c}{p_3p_4}\right)^2-\left(\frac{b}{p_2p_3}+\frac{d}{p_1p_4}\right)^2}{ap_3p_4+cp_1p_2+bp_4p_1+dp_2p_3}$$ $$=\frac{2ac-2bd+p_1p_2p_3p_4\left(\frac{a^2}{p_1^2p_2^2}+\frac{c^2}{p_3^2p_4^2}-\frac{b^2}{p_2^2p_3^2}-\frac{d^2}{p_1^2p_4^2}\right)}{ap_3p_4+cp_1p_2+bp_4p_1+dp_2p_3}\ \ (*)$$
The cosine formula for triangle $APB$ gives $a^2=p_1^2+p_2^2-2p_1p_2\cos APB$. Similarly for $CPD$, so we get $\frac{a^2}{p_1^2p_2^2}+\frac{c^2}{p_3^2p_4^2}=k-\frac{2}{p_1p_2}\cos APB-\frac{2}{p_3p_4}\cos APB$, where $k=\frac{1}{p_1^2}+\frac{1}{p_2^2}+\frac{1}{p_3^2}+\frac{1}{p)4^2}$. For the other two triangles we have $b^2=p_2^2+p_3^2+2p_2p_3\cos APB$ and $d^2=p_4^2+p_1^2+2p_1p_4\cos APB$, so $\frac{b^2}{p_2p_3}+\frac{d^2}{p^1p_4}=k+\frac{2}{p_2p_3}\cos APB+\frac{2}{p_1p_4}\cos APB$. So the denominator of $(*)$ becomes $$2ac-2bd-2\left(p_3p_4+p_1p_2+p_1p_4+p_2p_3\right)\cos APB$$ Using the cosine formula again this becomes $$2ac-2bd+(a^2-p_1^2-p_2^2+c^2-p_3^2-p_4^2-b^2+p_2^2+p_4^2-d^2+p_1^2+p_3^2)$$ $$=2ac-2bd+a^2+c^2-b^2-d^2=(a+c)^2-(b+d)^2$$ So we have finally $$\left(\frac{1}{r_1}+\frac{1}{r_3}-\frac{1}{r_2}-\frac{1}{r_4}\right)\sin\angle APB=\frac{(a+c)^2-(b+d)^2}{ap_3p_4+cp_1p_2+bp_4p_1+dp_2p_3}$$ It is well-known that the necessary and sufficient condition for a quadrilateral sides (in order) $a,b,c,d$ to have an incircle is $a+c=b+d$. Since $\sin\angle APB\ne0$ for a non-degenerate quadrilateral, we have just established that $a+c=b+d$ iff $\frac{1}{r_1}+\frac{1}{r_3}=\frac{1}{r_2}+\frac{1}{r_4}$ and so this also a necessary and sufficient condition for an incircle.